# Как найти разницу во времени?

Tags: java, android

Есть `String dat = "2017-10-26 09:33:15.133";` надо найти разницу между этим временем и текущей датой.желательно в секундах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Duration getDuration(ZonedDateTime z1, ZonedDateTime z2) {
    return  Duration.between(z1, z2);
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
```

Пример использования:

```
String dateStr = "2017-10-26 09:33:15.133 Z";
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, DATE_FORMAT);

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

System.out.println(getDuration(date, now).getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 1):

Конвертируйте данную строку в миллисекунды. Потом вычитайте из текущего времени в миллисекундах (если java то можно воспользоваться `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`) полученный результат. В итоге получите разницу в миллисекундах. Эту разницу будет легко преобразовать в минуты, часы и тд.

Comment: Комментируйте, когда минусы ставите пожалуйста.